# Problema con dimensión entre etiquetas body y thead tabla html

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, reactjs

Hola Estoy tratando de mostrar una tabla con datos en react.js y estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de hacer el render como se muestra en la imagen. Estoy utilizando la misma estructura en un proyecto laravel y funciona perfecto. Alguna sugerencia?

Código:

```
class ListadoDeProductos extends Component{
render(){
return(
<div className="col-md-6">
  <h3>Listado de Productos</h3>
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Precio</th>
        <th>Acción</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <body>
      {Object.keys(this.props.productos).map(key => 
      <Producto handleAddOrden={this.props.handleAddOrden}
      key={key} 
      index={key}
      detalles={this.props.productos[key]} />)
      }
     </body>
     </table>
    </div>);
   }
   }
  export default ListadoDeProductos;

class Producto extends Component{
handleClick = () =>{
    this.props.handleAddOrden(this.props.index);
}
render(){
const {codigo, nombre, precio} = this.props.detalles;
return(
    <tr>
        <td>{codigo}</td>
        <td>{nombre}</td>
        <td>{precio}</td>
        <td><button onClick={this.handleClick}> -> Carro</button></td>
     </tr>
    );
 }
 }
  export default Producto;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que el error está en que es `tbody` y no `body` dentro de tu tabla

Comment: Es correcto amigo. Graicias